# How to make CSS transition work using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am taking reference from :
https://codepen.io/SudhakarJ/pen/GRgpddL    .
I want to make same transition effect in my application, where I have 10 images and I use 3 classes namely cars,animals and fruits and when I click they should be filtered.
But the animated filter selector is not performing transition

HTML

```
<div class="section"> 
    <div id="wrapper-filter">
        <ul id="filter-bar">
            <span class="pill" style="color:#212121"></span>
            <li class="filter-option option-1 active" onclick="filterSelection('all')" style="color:#fffefe">All</li>
            <li class="filter-option option-2" onclick="filterSelection('cars')" style="color:#fffefe">Shoes</li>
            <li class="filter-option option-3" onclick="filterSelection('animals')" style="color:#fffefe">Toys</li>
            <li class="filter-option option-4" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')" style="color:#fffefe">Toys</li>                        
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css

```
body {background-color:#ffffff; margin: 0; padding:0; font-family: Tahoma;}
h2 {text-align:center;}
#filter-bar {width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; height:36px; display:inline-flex;}
#wrapper-filter {background-color:#000; width: 570px; height:auto; margin:30px auto; border-radius: 30px; box-sizing: border-box;}
#filter-bar li {width: 190px;background-color: transparent; text-align: center; list-style-type: none;z-index:10; cursor: pointer; font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif; font-weight: 100; font-size: 15px;line-height:36px;}
.pill {position: absolute; width:190px; height: 38px; background-color: #39c; border-radius: 30px; color: #444; z-index:10; border: 5px solid #eee; box-sizing: border-box; }
.filter-option {transition: color 500ms;}
    #filter-bar.option-1 .pill {margin-left: 0px; transition: margin-left 200ms ease;}
#filter-bar.option-2 .pill {margin-left: 187px; transition: margin-left 200ms ease;}
#filter-bar.option-3 .pill {margin-left: 380px; transition: margin-left 200ms ease;}

.option-1.active, .option-2.active, .option-3.active {color:#FFD700; transition: color 200ms; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter-bar li").click(function() {
        $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active")
        $(this).addClass("active")
        $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target"))
    })
})
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and add missing elements like the `filterSelection` method to help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an adapted version of the codepen where:

- menu width is changed from 570px to 760px to take in account the 4 elements instead of 3 (it could maybe done in a dynamic way to take in account any number of items)
- item width is unchanged (190px)
- `onclick=filterSelection` custom method is removed. JS retrieves the class to apply using the `data-target-filter` attr
- CSS transitions rules are updated with your options (`.all, .car, .animals, .fruits` instead of example `.option-1,.option-2,.option-3`) so they match when the value is applied as a class on `#bar-filter`

```js
$("#filter-bar li").click(function() {
  $("#filter-bar li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#filter-bar").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("data-target-filter"));
});
```

```css
#filter-bar {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

#wrapper-filter {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 760px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#filter-bar li {
  width: 190px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.pill {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 38px;
  background-color: #39c;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #212121: z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filter-option {
  transition: color 500ms;
  color: #fffefe;
}

#filter-bar.all .pill {
  margin-left: 0px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.cars .pill {
  margin-left: 190px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.animals .pill {
  margin-left: 380px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

#filter-bar.fruits .pill {
  margin-left: 570px;
  transition: margin-left 200ms ease;
}

.all.active,
.cars.active,
.animals.active,
.fruits.active {
  color: #FFD700;
  transition: color 200ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <div id="wrapper-filter">
    <ul id="filter-bar">
      <span class="pill"></span>
      <li class="filter-option all active" data-target-filter="all">All</li>
      <li class="filter-option cars" data-target-filter="cars">Shoes</li>
      <li class="filter-option animals" data-target-filter="animals">Toys</li>
      <li class="filter-option fruits" data-target-filter="fruits">Fruits</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```